# Не могу получить номер входящего звонка

Tags: android

Нашел несколько ответов тут, но не один не заработал у меня. Где ошибка?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLog";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    // CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // CALL_STATE_RINGING
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"CALL_STATE_RINGING " + incomingNumber);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: что именно не получается?

Comment: Номер не отдает он мне. Log.d(LOG_TAG,"CALL_STATE_RINGING " + incomingNumber);

Comment: А что отдает? null? или не вызывается? Давайте мы не будем клещами с вас тянуть, а вы расскажете сами

Comment: Разрешения добавлены нужные?

Comment: При звонке пишет в лог CALL_STATE_RINGING, и все, номера нет. Разрешения такие: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

Comment: Попробуйте на других телефонах, возможно ваш телефон не соответствует спецификации google

Comment: Думал уже об этом, на эмуляторе тоже не работает (